# Search for value from the console (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, console.log

When I open the console, I would like to be able to search for a value instead of having to browse through it. Is there any easy way to do it ?

For instance, in the case below I used *console.log(element.style)* in JS. I would like to be able to input somewhere in the console *height* or *100px* and that every occurrence appears instead of having to browse through the output (see below).
[image]

Is there any easy way to achieve that in Firefox ?

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on `CSS2Properties` => `Store as Global Variable`, and the variable `temp` will be available in the console